# expand and reorder an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, data-structures

i have and array

```
    reservation1:[
      {name:"8:30",active:true,dayindex:1},
      {name:"jad",active:true,dayindex:3},
    ]
```

i need to expand the array to 9 
and fill it with object with name null active false dayindex: between 0 and 10 in order 
the output needed is

```
  output =[
   {name:"",active:false,dayindex:0}
   {name:"8:30",active:true,dayindex:1}

    ...
```

i tried this for expanding

it worked for expanding but i couldnt reorder it as i wanted

Comment: Discuss this on chat?

Comment: Yh please sir ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort you array after adding others elements:

```js
var reservation = [
    {name:"8:30",active:true,dayindex:1},
    {name:"jad",active:true,dayindex:3},
    {name:"tony",active:true,dayindex:4},
    {name:"",active:false,dayindex:6}
];
var availabeDayIndex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(el => !reservation.map(it => it.dayindex).includes(el));
var sortField = 'dayindex';
reservation = [...reservation, ...Array.from(Array(9 - reservation.length), (val, key) => ({name: null, active: false, dayindex: availabeDayIndex[key]}))].sort((a, b) => a[sortField] - b[sortField]);
console.log(reservation);
```

Comment: dayindex to to be a variable it is changeable

Comment: dayindex will vary from 0 to 10 filling the required position here dayindex need to fill {0 2 5 7 8 9 }